# Can't convert DD-MON-YYYY to MM//DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, date

```
    SELECT distinct
     CM_NAME, 
     Booking_Date,
     sum(DogRevenue) as TTL_DogREV,
     sum(Room_Revenue) as TTL_ROOM,
     sum(Car_Revenue) AS TTL_CAR,
     sum(Activity_Revenue) as TTL_ACT,
     0 as TTL_CRUISE,
     sum(Dog_Rev + Room + Car + Activity) as 
     TTL_BOOK

     from

       (SELECT         
            internalagentname as CM_NAME,
            resvCode AS Booking_Number,
            transactionDate AS "Transaction_Date",
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), initialbookingdate, 101) as Booking_Date
```

for some reason i keep getting an error when trying to convert bookingdate to MM/DD/YYYY as it is currently in the following format: DD-MON-YYYY (01-FEB-2018)

i keep getting expression missing error

Comment: Your are using SQL Server functions in a question tagged Oracle.  That might be the root cause of the problem.

Comment: thanks! still a noob and didn't know sql server has different functions than oracle

Answer (score 0):

Convert to date first before converting to varchar(10) like this:

select convert(varchar(10),cast('01-FEB-2018' as date) , 101)

Comment: @kamranmalik have check this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/8758 from working?